# Better way for login with QR Code

Tags: c#, sql, authentication, websocket, qr-code

It is a lock application for desktop. When user read QR Code with smart phone app program will open like whatsapp web.

I know whatsapp using websocket for this but its looks hard for me. I didn't get it.

So what is my solution:
In desktop when press create QR Code. QR Code is generating and 5 seconds later following SQL Code running:

```
SELECT isQRok FROM logins WHERE appid=this.id;
```

If result will 1 login else do nothing.

And before this 5 seconds if user read QR code with mobile app. Mobile app will run this sql.

```
INSERT INTO logins (isQRok, appid) values(1,readedQr.appid);
```

This codes looks nice but this lock application will be using at public schools this means if I use this thousands sql code will run with my server IP and public schools firewall can block me so I am afraid for this.

Is there a better way for do this like multi-factor authentication api.

Comment: Could you detail a little bit more about if this is a server/client solution? If my understanding is correct, you are saying that the (1) application is locked, until the (2) user scans the QR code, which will then (3) authenticate the user and (4) unlock the application?

Comment: You should use an API which is called from the mobile app to complete the authentication. If you are running a SQL query which means you are keeping your server open and not behind a firewall which is a big security risk.

Comment: @Svek yes exactly like this.

Comment: @Vijay you right I know my solution have risk. Do you have an example api?